# Recover deleted file from PhpStorm and SourceTree

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, atlassian-sourcetree

I have an open project in PhpStorm that I manage using SourceTree.  I was trying to remove some image files from a commit using SourceTree, but accidentally selected a file that should not be deleted.  I haven't changed anything (in either PhpStorm or SourceTree) since deleting the file.  I tried to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in SourceTree but nothing happened.  I then checked in PhpStorm Vcs -> local history, but it didn't show the file.  How can I recover this file?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Try to right click on project main folder in phpStorm and select Local history / Show History in context menu (not vcs / local history). The file should be at the list as "Deleting".

Answer (score 1):

This is documented by JetBrains [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/02/local-history-in-intellij-idea-may-save-your-life-code/)

**TL;DR**

[image: screencast]